# InvocationTargetException when running an applet from the browser

Tags: java, applet, processing

I have an applet that uses the Processing (http://www.processing.org) library. The processing lib is contained in `core.jar` I'm trying to embed it in a webpage. Here is the html

```
<html>    
<body>
<applet width=300 height=300 code="Applet.class" archive="core.jar"> 
   no applet
</applet>
</body>    
</html>
```

The applet code is below

```
import processing.core.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


class Heart extends PApplet //subclass of Applet
{
    Particle p;
    ArrayList<Particle> particles;
    PImage heart;


    public void setup() //These are overrides of PApplet methods
    {
        ...do stuff...
    }

    public void draw() //These are overrides of PApplet methods
    {
        ...more stuff....
    }

    PVector randVec(float min, float max)
    {
      ...etc etc....
    }
}
```

I can post the full applet code but I don't know if it's necessary.

When I load the .html page. I get a java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException. There is no stack trace in the Java Console.

Answer (score 1):

2 problems:

1) Heart class should be public:

```
   public class Heart extends PApplet { 
      ...
```

2) Your applet tag should read:

```
<applet width=300 height=300 code="Heart.class" archive="core.jar">
```